# SOAP ERROR Parsing WSDL

Tags: workbench

I'm getting the following Error message on all pages of my workbench.

[image]

I've tried going into settings to lower the API version, but the error message above is the only item that will load on the page. Are there other troubleshooting steps that people have taken?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same issue. It can be solved by logging out of Workbench entirely and then re-logging in with the API version set to 41. You have to end the session and start over; you can't change the API version in Workbench settings once you get this error.